# .NET 7 supports JWT-signature verification against PUK ECDsa and Brainpool P256R1 alg?

Tags: c#, .net, jwt, cryptography, signature

EDIT: Issue solved.I am able to validate jwts signature against the public key of the x5c cert chain. Thank you, Topaco, your comment lead me to check my data once again. Solution on the bottom.

Im new on this topic, but Im trying to implement a jwt signature verification and dont want to use bouncy castle. The SigningCert(Chain) lies in the JWT's 'x5c' header. jwt-alg header says "bp256r1".

My problem is Im getting following ArgumentException as Validation Result:
IDX10645: Elliptical Curve not supported for curveId: 'brainpoolP256r1'

To be fair: That message doesnt leave much room for interpretation. But I thought, that with Win10 and Ongoing, BP256R1 algorithm is supported?.

What am i Missing?

thats my Code, I'd wish validation result is true, but it inst:

```cs
        public async Task<JwtSecurityToken> GetDiscoveryDocument()
        {
            //Get Token
            var response = await _client.GetAsync(".well-known/openid-configuration");
            response.EnsureSuccessStatusCode();
            
            //parse Token
            string token = await response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync(); 
            var jwtHandler = new JwtSecurityTokenHandler();
            var jwt = jwtHandler.ReadJwtToken(token);

            //Get SigningCert
            var x5cCerts = JsonSerializer.Deserialize<object[]>(jwt.Header["x5c"].ToString());
            X509Certificate2 cert = new X509Certificate2(Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(x5cCerts.First().ToString()));
            
            //Get PublicKey and Set validationParameters, ValidateSignature
            var ecdsa = cert.GetECDsaPublicKey();
            var vaidationResult = await jwtHandler.ValidateTokenAsync(token, new TokenValidationParameters
            {
                ValidateIssuer = false,
                ValidateAudience = false,
                ValidateLifetime = false,
                ValidateIssuerSigningKey = true,
                IssuerSigningKey = new ECDsaSecurityKey(ecdsa),                
            });

            return jwt;
        }
```

I also tried to use:

```cs
            var ecdsa = cert.GetECDsaPublicKey();
            byte[] data = ....;
            byte[] signature = ....;
            ecdsa.VerifyData(data, signature, HashAlgorithmName.SHA256);
```

Solution:

```cs
    public async Task<JwtSecurityToken> GetDiscoveryDocument()
    {
        //Get Token
        var response = await _client.GetAsync(".well-known/openid-configuration");
        response.EnsureSuccessStatusCode();
        
        //parse Token
        string token = await response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync(); 
        var jwtHandler = new JwtSecurityTokenHandler();
        var jwt = jwtHandler.ReadJwtToken(token);

        //Get SigningCert
        var x5cCerts = JsonSerializer.Deserialize<object[]>(jwt.Header["x5c"].ToString());
        X509Certificate2 cert = new X509Certificate2(Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(x5cCerts.First().ToString()));
        
        //Get PublicKey and Set validationParameters, ValidateSignature
        var ecdsa = cert.GetECDsaPublicKey();
        var valid = ecdsa.VerifyData(Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(jwt.EncodedHeader + "." + jwt.EncodedPayload), Base64UrlEncoder.DecodeBytes(jwt.RawSignature), HashAlgorithmName.SHA256);
            return jwt;
        }
```

Comment: Doesn't seem to be a .NET shortcoming to me. brainpoolP256r1 is not even supported by [Nimbus Jose](https://connect2id.com/products/nimbus-jose-jwt/examples/jws-with-ec-signature) and is not specified in [RFC7518](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc7518#section-3.4). [brainpoolP256r1](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.security.cryptography.eccurve.namedcurves.brainpoolp256r1?view=net-7.0#system-security-cryptography-eccurve-namedcurves-brainpoolp256r1) itself is supported by .NET, so the second approach should work. It's probably because of your data. Post sample data.

Comment: Hey @Topaco , thank you very much. your comment resolved my problem, it was as simple as Ive been stupid, I concatenated header and payload with using comma due to typo... 
I just wanted to add thats not my idea to use that algorithm, its given by the interfaces author. 

Would it be theoretically possible to implement a solution using JwtTokenHandler by deriving form ECDsaSecurityKey and ICryptoProvider?